# Is there an ESLint rule for doing only checked accesses to window?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Is there a lint rule or plugin that can enforce checking for the existence of window before accessing it? Something like

```
// OK
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.addEventListener(...);
}

// Should Reject:
window.addEventListener(...);
```

I'd rather have a lint rule that works for both Typescript and Javascript but I'd settle for a TS compiler option if there is one. Note that this may be for frontend code that's being SSR'd, I can't solve this by making it a node-only thing.

Comment: You can employ the `no-undef` rule to prevent the usage of variables that haven't been declared. Nevertheless this rule might not be completely effective because in web browsers, the "window" variable is considered global and `ESLint` may not flag it as undeclared when working in a browser environment.

Comment: @AztecCodes correct, it will not by default treat window as undefined.

Comment: Not without losing all type information from the `dom`-related libs (`@types/web`). It would be straightforward to omit those ambient types from compilation and then unset the global `window` varaible in ESLint, but then you'd have to [feature-detect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) `globalThis.window` and everything within. This pain is caused by the fact that the web types are shipped as ambient declarations rather than exported types from modules — so it's currently an all-or-nothing affair.